# Android: IllegalStateException thrown

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

In the LoginActivity.java class, when a user clicks a register button, then the code sets the login session true and then switches the activity from LoginActivity to MainActivity. Here's the login code snippet.

```
            case(R.id.login):
                String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                if(email.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                    loginManager.checkLogin(email, password);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in..");
                    showDialog();
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    if(loginManager.isLoginSuccessful()) {
                        hideDialog();
                        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.welcome_msg), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, loginManager.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } else if(email.trim().length() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter the email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter the password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
```

And here's the LoginManager.java file that deals with the login process. I used OkHttp for the HTTP library.

```
public class LoginManager {
    private final String TAG_LOGIN = LoginManager.class.getSimpleName();
    private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    private final String loginURL = URL.getInstance().getUrlLogin();
    private Request request = new Request.Builder().url(loginURL).build();

    private static JSONObject jsonObject;
    private boolean error;

    public void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            // onFailure is called when the request could not be executed due to cancellation, a connectivity problem or timeout.
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            // onResponse is called when the HTTP response was successfully returned by the remote server.
            // using POST request for login
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.d(TAG_LOGIN, "Login response: " + response.body().string());
                RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                        .add("tag", "login")
                        .add("email", email)
                        .add("password", password)
                        .build();
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url(loginURL).post(body).build();
                client.newCall(request).execute();

                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");
                } catch(JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isLoginSuccessful() {
        if(error) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        String errorMessage = null;
        try {
            jsonObject.getString("error_msg");
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return errorMessage;
    }
}
```

When I run the application, it shows the welcome toast message and suddenly quits with the following error log.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:454)
            at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:574)
            at okio.RealBufferedSource.readByteArray(RealBufferedSource.java:87)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody.bytes(ResponseBody.java:56)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:82)
            at com.marshall.thequizshow.application.http.LoginManager$1.onResponse(LoginManager.java:51)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:150)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

So, I must be having a bug with the try-catch phrase under the onResponse method in the LoginManager.java file.

```
try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");
                } catch(JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I would like to ask you how I should fix the code so that it no longer catches the IllegalStateException.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you sure that it is catching the exception .. `IllegalStateException` will not be caught by `JSONException` catch block because they are not in parent-child relationship .. I think the stack trace you are getting is normal which comes .. You can place a logger in the catch of  `JSONException` and you will see that it is not being logged, which means it is already not catching .. If you are not using `IllegalStateException` or `RuntimeException` or `Exception` then `IllegalStateException` will not be caught in any catch block ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general answer, YES: The proper way to avoid a RuntimeException is to fix the code: They should not be catched by program, under normal circunstances.

Now, let's see your case... The `IllegalStateException` arises because the HttpConnection seems to be closed when trying to use it. Could it be because you are calling twice the method `response.body()`?

Comment: You can only call response.body().string() once per response. Also beware if you have this sitting in your "watch" list as it will count as well. https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1240

Answer (score -2):

IllegalState exception is thrown when you call a method at a wrong time. Check the nature of your process then restructure you code to make the call at an appropriate time